# Infinite Family of Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ be a vector space of finite dimension and $F$ an infinite family of subspaces of $E$. $T$ is the subspace-intersection of all subspaces of $F$. Prove that there is a finite number $S_1,...,S_m$ of subspaces in $F$ such that $T=S_1{\cap}S_2{\cap}...{\cap}S_m$.

I tried to prove this but I have doubts with the method, I think it is building but I'm not sure, well I have not mastered very well the concept of infinite family, since I'm new in linear algebra. I hope you can help me, please.

Comment: Hint: if $U,W$ are two distinct subspaces of $V$ of dimension $k > 0$, then $\dim(U \cap W) < k$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but how i could better use an argument for the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector space $V$ is *Artinian* if every chain of subspaces 
$$
V\supset U_1\supset U_2\supset U_3\supset\dotsb\tag{1}
$$
stabilizes.

Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space with dimension $n$. Taking dimensions in (1) [gives](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dimension_of_Proper_Subspace_Less_Than_its_Superspace)
$$
n\geq n_1\geq n_2\geq n_3\geq\dotsb\geq 0\tag{2}
$$
where $n_k=\dim U_k$. Since the set of integers $\{n_1,n_2,n_3,\dotsc\}$ is bounded below by $0$, it has a minimal element $N$. Thus (2) ensures the existence of a $K$ such that $k\geq K$ implies $n_k=N$. Hence $k\geq K$ implies $U_k=U_K$. That is, our chain stabilizes.

This proves that every finite-dimensional vector space is Artinian.

Now, you have a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and an infinite collection of subspaces $S$. Note that [$S$ has a countably infinite subset](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Infinite_Set_has_Countably_Infinite_Subset) $\{S_1,S_2,\dotsc\}$.

Define a chain of subspaces of $V$ by
$$
U_k=\bigcap_{i=1}^k S_i
$$
What can we conclude about these subspaces? How does this address your problem?